# Markdown-like tool for converting "human" text to reasonable LaTeX code?

Tags: conversion, tools, markdown

In my ideal world, I *want* to be able to write something like

```
So here are the steps:
- So now we define x^* = min { x | sum_kk ||f(x_kk^20)|| } and then do blah
    - But this requires another indented bullet point with a couple equations:
        a = 1/2 + 1
        b = c + d
- Now I have another step
```

and have it automagically converted to something reasonably similar in LaTeX, such as:

```
So here are the steps:
\begin{itemize}
    \item So now we define $x^* = \min \left\{ x \middle| \sum_{kk} \lVert f(x_{kk}^{20}) \rVert \right\}$ and then do blah
        \begin{itemize}
            \item But this requires another indented bullet point
            \begin{align*}
                a &= 1/2 + 1  \\
                b &= c + d
            \end{align*}
        \begin{itemize}
    \item Now I have another step
\end{itemize}
```

I realize there's probably no tool that does *exactly* what  I want, but is there any tool that helps me do anything even remotely like this, to help me save my fingers and type less?

#### Note:

1. I'm **not** trying to convert handwriting. There is another question about that already.
2. The "correct" output is subjective. That's OK. I merely want something reasonable.
3. If needed, I can type `$...$` and `\` and all, but I want to type as little as possible.
   By **far** the most painful things to type are `\begin{ENVIRONMENT}...\end{ENVIRONMENT}`, `\left...\middle...\right`, and such verbose constructs.

Comment: Please read Hans’ discussion of ASCIIMATH in [this TUGboat](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113hagen.pdf).  Also note his comment in [`x-asciimath.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/modules/mkiv/x-asciimath.mkiv): »It must be noted that simplified encodings (that seem to be the fashion today) can demand from applications to apply fuzzy logic to make something work out well.«

Comment: So my advice is, forget about everything you learned about Markdown or other highly ambiguous input methods and stick to full TeX markup.  It is the *only* reliable way to determine exactly how your input will be typeset.  There is no point in exchanging a little time to type extra markup by a lot of time to fix weird rendering and ugly typography.  Just use an editor with good autocompletion.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/) which can convert from non-verbose input languages like Markdown to LaTeX.

Comment: It starts already in your question.  You demand that `x_kk^20` is converted to `x_kk^{20}`.  How should the parser decide that?  Why is it not converted to `x_{kk}^{20}` or `x_kk^20` which are entirely different things?

Comment: @HenriMenke: That was a typo...

Comment: @Mehrdad Then how would you input `x_{kk^{20}}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke: `x_{kk^20}` or just `x_(kk^20)`. I'm flexible...

Comment: @Mehrdad No, that is turned into `x_\left\{ kk^{20} \right\}` or `x_(kk^{20})` according to your proposed input method (the first of which is not valid TeX and the second not giving the intended rendering).

Comment: @HenriMenke: No, it doesn't. That's a subscript, my example in the question is not. There's a 99% chance that when I write `x_{kk^20}` I intend it to turn into `x_{kk^{20}}` and not `x_\left\{ kk^{20} \right\}`, so the converter should convert it into that. If I need otherwise I can write it explicitly myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52134/discussion-between-henri-menke-and-mehrdad).

Comment: You might also be interested in this: https://github.com/cben/mathdown/wiki/math-in-markdown

Comment: maybe https://www.ctan.org/pkg/easylist?lang=en would be interesting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Turns out [it exists and is called ASCIIMath](https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml)!

It seems to convert math in HTML into MathML, for MathJax to render.

After that, if you really want LaTeX code, you can convert MathML to LaTeX with a standard utility. Otherwise you can just use the rendered output directly.

Comment: This answer would be useful if it actually showed the steps one would take to convert a simple example to TeX output. That is, the ASCII example file, the commands one runs, and the resulting output.

Comment: @jon: There's no commands though, it's just HTML markup with 2 lines of loading Javascript. Or is that what you want to see?

Comment: Well, I assume if input is being 'converted' to output (as your question seems to ask), it seems that any useful answer will include at least two things: (i) a description of how to do it from an end-user perspective; and (ii) an example of the input and output so end-users can verify that they are getting the expected output.  Alternatively, if neither of those things make sense for ASCIIMath, then I'd think a useful answer for people unfamiliar with the utility would include details that explicitly or implicitly indicate why neither (i) nor (ii) are relevant.

Comment: @jon: Gotcha. Yeah, this tool doesn't convert to LaTeX; it just renders it directly using MathJax & MathML. So I guess it doesn't strictly answer the question, but there are tools to convert MathML to LaTeX. I haven't actually done the last step of the conversion (or even cared about MathML) since getting it to render was already good enough for me, at least right now. (Notice I asked the question myself...)

Comment: Ah, OK. Now the answer makes sense (without needing to click on the link and read an off-site wepage or two).

Answer (score 5):

As we discussed in the comments and in chat, there is no way to parse math in an unambiguous fashion.  Therefore, most tools to convert something to LaTeX do not implement any sophisticated math parsing techniques as shown in your question.

The `pandoc` tool however, accepts inline LaTeX math.  Consider the following example saved as `test.md`

```
So here are the steps:

- So now we define $x^* = \min\left\{ x \middle| \sum_{kk} \|f(x_{kk}^{20})\| \right\}$ and then do blah
    - But this requires another indented bullet point with a couple equations:
      \begin{align*}
        a &= 1/2 + 1 \\
        b &= c + d \\
      \end{align*}
- Now I have another step
```

Now you can used `pandoc` to convert this snippet to LaTeX.

```bash
pandoc -f markdown -t latex -o test.tex test.md
```

The resulting `text.tex` will have the contents

```
So here are the steps:

\begin{itemize}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item
  So now we define
  $x^* = \min\left\{ x \middle| \sum_{kk} \|f(x_{kk}^{20})\| \right\}$
  and then do blah

  \begin{itemize}
  \itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
  \item
    But this requires another indented bullet point with a couple
    equations:

    \begin{align*}
        a &= 1/2 + 1 \\
        b &= c + d \\
      \end{align*}
  \end{itemize}
\item
  Now I have another step
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: if `pandoc` leaves a blank line before display math, it's doing a bad disservice. hope that's a misunderstanding.